# Typecasting an integer to a character pointer in C

Tags: c, embedded, casting

I have a function `uint8_t EE_Write(uint8_t addr, uint8_t len, uint8_t * buf)` that takes a pointer to some data that it will write to memory, and a `uint16_t myword` that I want to give it.  The basic

```
EE_Write(0,sizeof(myword),&myword);
```

gives me the compiler warning "Indirection to different types ('unsigned int *const ' instead of 'unsigned char *const ')"  Even when I typecast the word (int) to a byte (char), I received the exact same warning (and no amount of grouping with parenthesis helped).

```
EE_Write(0,sizeof(myword),&(uint8_t)myword);
```

Warnings go away with a union, but it's asinine to have to write it to another variable just to make the compiler happy.

```
union catbyte {
    uint16_t w;
    uint8_t b[2];
};

union catbyte mybytes;

mybytes.w = myword;
EE_Write(0,sizeof(myword),mybytes.b);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
EE_Write(0,sizeof(myword),(uint8_t *)&myword);
```

But the prefered way of doing this would be to define the function to take a void pointer like:

```
uint8_t EE_Write(uint8_t addr, uint8_t len, const void * buf);
```

And then the compiler shouldn't warn you about it for any pointer type you pass.

Comment: Ah, should of looked at `memcpy`, etc. to get a clue.